# For Next Loop that computes wrong?

Tags: vb.net, loops

I am attempting to build a program in Visual Basic 2010 that computes an hourly wage into a yearly number (eg. 10*40*52) and a percent increase on that yearly number and reflect that over 10 years. My main problem is that when I get to the for next loop which is supposed to iterate the math 9 times (the first is fixed), I am finding that the code stores the value from the first iteration and uses that in the next 8 iterations. How can I keep this from happening. Please keep in mind I am new to programming to try to keep it simple. Thanks!

```
option Strict On

Public Class frmPayCalculator

Private Sub btnComputeFuturePay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnComputeFuturePay.Click
    ' The btnComputeFuturePay event accepts accepts hourly wage and pay raise
    ' information, and then displays the yearly pay over the next ten years.

    Dim decHourlyWage As Decimal
    Dim decYearlyWageComputed As Decimal
    Dim decExpectedRaise As Decimal
    Dim decExpectedRaiseComputed As Decimal
    Dim intYears As Integer
    Dim decIncrementedYearlyWage As Decimal

    If IsNumeric(txtHourlyWage.Text) Then
        ' Convert input to decimal.
        decHourlyWage = Convert.ToDecimal(txtHourlyWage.Text)
        ' Data validation to check if input is a positive.
        If decHourlyWage > 0 Then
            decYearlyWageComputed = decHourlyWage * 40 * 52
            lstDecadeWage.Items.Add("Year 1" & " - Wage: " & decYearlyWageComputed.ToString("C"))
        Else
            ' Error for negative number
            lstDecadeWage.Items.Clear()
            txtHourlyWage.Focus()
            MsgBox("You have entered a negative number for Hourly' Data validation to check if input is a number. Rate, try again with a positive number", , "Input Error")
        End If
        ' Data validation to check if input is a number.
        If IsNumeric(txtExpectedRaise.Text) Then
            ' Convert Data to decimal
            decExpectedRaise = Convert.ToDecimal(txtExpectedRaise.Text)
            ' Divide the whole number by 100 to make it a percent.
            decExpectedRaiseComputed = decExpectedRaise / 100
        Else
            ' Error for non-number: Expected Raise percent.
            lstDecadeWage.Items.Clear()
            txtHourlyWage.Focus()
            MsgBox("You have entered a non-number for the Expected Raise, try again with a number.", , "Input Error")
        End If
    Else
        ' Error for non-number: Hourly Rate.
        lstDecadeWage.Items.Clear()
        txtHourlyWage.Focus()
        MsgBox("You have entered a non-number for Hourly Rate, try again with a number.", , "Input Error")
    End If

    For intYears = 2 To 10
        decIncrementedYearlyWage += (decYearlyWageComputed + decYearlyWageComputed * decExpectedRaiseComputed)
        lstDecadeWage.Items.Add("Year " & intYears & " - Wage: " & decIncrementedYearlyWage.ToString("c"))
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub mnuClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuClear.Click
    ' The mnuClear click event that clears the ListBox object, Wage and Raise Textboxes and, enables the Compute
    ' Future Pay button.

End Sub

Private Sub mnuExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuExit.Click
    ' The mnuExit click event closes the window and exits the application.
    Close()

End Sub


Private Sub frmPayCalculator_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Preload event that clears the ListBox object, Wage and Raise Textboxes and, enables the Compute
    ' Future Pay button.

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
decIncrementedYearlyWage += (decYearlyWageComputed + decYearlyWageComputed * decExpectedRaiseComputed)
```

which is going to give the same result each iteration because the values in the formula don't change, you might be looking for something like this:

```
decIncrementedYearlyWage += (decIncrementedYearlyWage * decExpectedRaiseComputed)
```

Comment: I knew I was running into some logic error on my end. At first I didn't understand why the solution worked, but it makes perfect sense. Each time the iteration ran the value from the iteration was stored and then used again and again. So the values in the list box would increase, but only by what the first value was.

Answer (score 0):

For example: HourlyWage = 5, ExpectedRaise = 10

with these data, if you're trying to do the following:

```
Year 1 - Wage: $ 10,400.00
Year 2 - Wage: $ 11,440.00
Year 3 - Wage: $ 12,584.00
Year 4 - Wage: $ 13,842.40
Year 5 - Wage: $ 15,226.64
Year 6 - Wage: $ 16,749.30
Year 7 - Wage: $ 18,424.23
Year 8 - Wage: $ 20,266.66
Year 9 - Wage: $ 22,293.32
Year 10 - Wage: $ 24,522.66
```

Then you must do:

```
For intYears = 2 To 10
    decYearlyWageComputed += decYearlyWageComputed * decExpectedRaiseComputed
    lstDecadeWage.Items.Add("Year " & intYears & " - Wage: " & decYearlyWageComputed.ToString("c"))
Next
```